# Rewirte Rules in Nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I conisder moving to Nginx but I want you to ask if is possible to rewrite urls into that schema, and if you could help me a bit:

- A url like **example.com/username** into **profile.php?u=username**. But then, will I have problems in accessing other pages like e.g. home.php
- A url like **example.com/questions/102039/that-question** into **questions.php?quid=102039**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If "username" is only letters and numbers, no `.`s or `/`s, then you can probably create a rule something like

```
rewrite ^/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ /profile.php?u=$1 last;
```

The first half of that command is the request from the client.  The second half is what we want to convert that request to.  `last` means to stop trying to rewrite this request.

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, `[A-Za-z0-9]` essentially means one character between A and Z or a and z or 0 and 9.  The `+` afterwards expands that to mean "a string of at least one in a row".  By wrapping it in `()` we are able to save that string, and refer to it as `$1` in the second half (if we had more than one sets of parentheses then the second would be $2 and so on).  Finally, the `^` means the beginning of the request, and the `$` means the endig.  So, a request for `/home.php` would not be rewritten because it does not start with / followed by a string of letters and numbers that reach to the end of the URL because of the `.` in the middle.

I've seen people use

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
  rewrite ...;
}
```

which solves the problem of "what if there really was a file named that" without relying on specific username patterns.

The second one could be

```
rewrite ^/questions/([0-9]+)/ /questions.php?quid=$1 last;
```

Note that this one didn't use the `$`, since we don't care about how the URL ends, all we need is that it starts with `/questions/` and has a number, followed by a slash..

You can read more about nginix's rewriting capability [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule).